# Cuba Platform Frontend UI entitities don't appear

Tags: java, backend, cuba-platform

I created a frontend module using cuba platform and an account entity, however when the page is loaded none of the names or photos are presented in the table. If you look into network it shows that get query returns only entity name, empty instance name and id. How to fix this? I have no experience in java or backend

```
package com.company.exercise.entity;

import com.haulmont.chile.core.annotations.NamePattern;
import com.haulmont.cuba.core.entity.StandardEntity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Table(name = "EXERCISE_CONTACTS")
@Entity(name = "exercise_Contacts")
@NamePattern("%s|value")
public class Contacts extends StandardEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5180754450963558385L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Account account;

    @Column(name = "CONTACT_TYPE", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String contactType;

    @Column(name = "VALUE_", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String value;

    public void setContactType(ContactType contactType) {
        this.contactType = contactType == null ? null : contactType.getId();
    }

    public ContactType getContactType() {
        return contactType == null ? null : ContactType.fromId(contactType);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: there is a lot of code, so I do not think that's possible, I'm just looking for some explanation

Comment: i added the code of entity, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this user doesn't have attribute permissions for the entity assigned.
All attributes are inaccessible by default and should be explicitly permitted via a runtime or design-time role, even if "read" operation for this entity is already permitted.

Example code for design-time role:

```
    @EntityAttributeAccess(entityClass = Contacts.class, modify = "*")
    @Override
    public EntityAttributePermissionsContainer entityAttributePermissions() {
        return super.entityAttributePermissions();
    }
```

Also the role assigned to the user should have "REST" scope, in order to be taken into account by REST API client.

https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/roles.html